# Count the number of cells in a dynamic range with a criteria

Tags: excel

This is a sample of the data I have:

[image: This is a sample of the data I have]
I'm trying to count the number of kids in a house based on the age values I have in D column. Anybody under the age of 18 is a kid. I want the values in the green box. This is obviously a small sample. The actual data is thousands of rows.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Also those borders will not do. While it is a good visual separator for humans, it is a terrible one for computer (interpreters). You have no denominator per house

Comment: In C2 I used this:

=IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",COUNTIF(OFFSET(D2,0,0,B2,1),"<=18"))

and it worked. But thanks you all.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of members per house is accurate, you can use

```
  =IF(A2="","",COUNTIF(INDEX(D:D,ROW()):INDEX(D:D,ROW()+B2-1),"<18"))
```

[image]